# how do I remove my public key from github?

Tags: github, public-key

I've got a public linked to my profile on github. I put it up a long time ago.
Since the time I put it up, I've lost the private key of the pair.

I have generated a new key pair and put it on my github profile. But I still can't push to github. git gives me errors related to my keys.

I'd like to remove the old public key, but I can't seem to find the option to do so in githubs admin dashboards. I can't find any instructions for how to remove keys. I've emailed them for help, but haven't gotten a reply as of yet.

How can I remove existing keys in my github account?

Answer (score 2):

To remove an SSH public key, follow the below steps.

1. Login to your GitHub account.
2. Go to the account Settings.
3. Follow the link 'SSH keys' at `/settings/ssh`.
4. Note your key in a list, represented as an email address (or compare with `ssh-add -l`).
5. Simply click on the 'Delete' next to your key.

That should do it.

Comment: I've figured it out, but the process is a different from your description. gh won't allow you to delete the key unless you delete the email address associated with it.  So, to change your key, you have to create a new email address and delete the old one. If you want to keep your email address, you have to delete it and then recreate it. It's a weird and inconvenient process.