# Git repo access issue

Tags: git, ssh, https

I have added ssh key to my git repo through below command and now getting below error:

```
CMD git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/

 Error : User1’s-MacBook-Pro:untitled folder ndpiparava$ git clone  https://github.com/XXX-Asft/XXXX
Cloning into 'XXXXX'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have realised that I have made mistake by setting up ssh instead of Https.
Is there any way that I can remove my ip from ssh list for my remote git and start using https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/

This means any url starting with `https://github.com/` will be rewritten with `ssh://git@github.com/`.

There is no "ip from ssh list for my remote git" to remove.

You can simply [delete that global config setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11868676/6309).

```
git config --global --unset url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf
```

And you can [remove your public key you set on your GitHub account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6742687/6309).